# SketchUp: dow to make a hole in a complex component?

Tags: sketchup

I have a big cube made up of many smaller cubes. Theoretically, all surfaces should be paralei/perpendicular, but maybe I didn't alligh something (I can be sure). Also, each layer of my big cube is shifted with respect to the previous one by half of the length of side of the smaller cube. So the odd and the even layers are aligned, but an odd layer isn't alligned to an even layer.

I'd like to make s hole trougout the cube, The hole should intersect surfaces of the smaller cubes.

I've found numerous examples of how to make a hole in one component (using the push/pull tool): [1](http://help.sketchup.com/en/article/3000100), [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f1Kc6xakxgM), [3](http://forums.sketchup.com/t/is-using-push-pull-a-good-way-to-make-a-hole/747/10). However, I haven't found any information on how to deal with such a complex component . How can I make a hole throughout my cube?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of creating a hole is to make a figure in form of the hole (for example, a long cylinder or parallelogram) and use it to create the hole.

After creating the figure, compose it to group (let's name it "hole" group) and move it into place of the hole. Make this group as subgroup of the target group. Then use intersect tool: select "hole" group and call "Intersect Faces / With Context" in context menu. After that it is need to delete unneeded parts in the target group.

Step by step solution:

1. Create a figure of the hole form, group it and give "hole" name.
2. Move "hole" into the place of the required hole.
3. Arrange "hole" as subgroup of the target group.
4. Intersect "hole" group with Context (i.e. parent group that is our target).
5. Remove unneeded parts in the target group.

The issue is that every subgroup should be edited separately, and to remove unneeded parts it is need to arrange "hole" into this subgroup and do intersection again.

To create inner surface of the hole we can use copy of the "hole" group as matter. Make copy, paste it in place, rename to "surface", arrange it into target group (if any). Then open "surface" group for edit, select all, call "Intersect Faces / With Model" in context menu. Note that intersection will be done with visible parts of the model only. After that delete unneeded parts in "surface" and optionally explode "surface" group. Use layers and hide/unhide tool to temporary hide interfering parts of the model.